# PHP - Gravity forms dynamic population multiple hidden fields based on URL

Tags: php, gravityforms

I am having issues with populating multiple dynamic fields in gravity forms. I can get this to populate one field, am I missing something?

I want to avoid duplicating the bottom solution as there will be 100 employees then times this by 6, would make updating this not ideal as this will be in the functions.php in wordpress.

Thanks,
Adam

```
function expert() {
  $currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  $person = object();
  if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-1') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 4021,
                  department_id: 19, 
                  ar_id: 2982, 
                  pvc_id: 2982, 
                  manager_id: 3360, 
                  office_id: 1559;
    return $person;
  } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-2') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 3654,
                  department_id: 3750, 
                  ar_id: 3654, 
                  pvc_id: 3654, 
                  manager_id: 3656, 
                  office_id: 9182;
    return $person;
  } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-3') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 3361,
                  department_id: 2592, 
                  ar_id: 2829, 
                  pvc_id: 2829, 
                  manager_id: 2836, 
                  office_id: 1559;
    return $person;
  } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-4') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 3129,
                  department_id: 3750, 
                  ar_id: 2046, 
                  pvc_id: 2046, 
                  manager_id: 2081, 
                  office_id: 1559;
    return $person;
  } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-5') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 3586,
                  department_id: 19, 
                  ar_id: 3065, 
                  pvc_id: 3065, 
                  manager_id: 3066, 
                  office_id: 1559;
    return $person;
  } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-6') !== false) {
        $person = expert_id: 2782,
                  department_id:  19, 
                  ar_id: 2533, 
                  pvc_id: 2533, 
                  manager_id: 2536, 
                  office_id: 1559;
    return $person;
  } else {
    return 4103;
  }
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_expert_id', 'populate_expert_id_field' );
function populate_expert_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['partner']) ? $expert_info['partner'] : '');
}
  
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_department_id', 'populate_department_id_field' );
function populate_department_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['department']) ? $expert_info['department'] : '');
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_ar_id', 'populate_ar_id_field' );
function populate_ar_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['ar']) ? $expert_info['ar'] : '');
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_pvc_id', 'populate_pvc_id_field' );
function populate_pvc_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['pvc']) ? $expert_info['pvc'] : '');
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_manager_id', 'populate_manager_id_field' );
function populate_manager_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['manager']) ? $expert_info['manager'] : '');
}

add_filter( 'gform_field_value_office_id', 'populate_office_id_field' );
function populate_office_id_field( $value ) {
  $expert_info = businessunithead();
  return (isset($expert_info['office']) ? $expert_info['office'] : '');
}
```

This code works for a single dynamic field.

```
function expert() {
  $currentUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-1') !== false) {
    return 4021;
    } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-2') !== false) {
      return 3654;
    } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-3') !== false) {
      return 3361;
    } else if (strpos($currentUrl, 'employee-4') !== false) {
      return 3129;
```

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_value_expert_id', 'populate_field' );
function populate_field( $value ) {
  return expert();
```

Comment: What is the actual structure of your URLs? It should probably be possible to _extract_ the `employee-X` value from that, so that you don't have to poke around with `strpos`. When you have the exact value, then your if-else if-...-else construct in `expert` can become a simple look-up in an array.

Comment: You don't have to add a filter for each field individually - see https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_value_parameter_name/#h-usage

Comment: https://website.com.au/experts/employee-lastname/

Comment: so it would be better to use the actual url instead?

Comment: are you talking about this, add_filter( 'gform_field_value_list', 'populate_list' );
function populate_list( $value ) {
  $list_array = array(
            array(
                'Column 1' => 'row1col1',
                'Column 2' => 'row1col2',
                'Column 3' => 'row1col3',
            ),
            array(
                'Column 1' => 'row2col1',
                'Column 2' => 'row2col2',
                'Column 3' => 'row2col3'
            ),
  );
    return $list_array;
}

Comment: No, I am talking about using the `gform_field_value` filter, and handling _everything_ in there.

Comment: _"so it would be better to use the actual url instead?"_ - extract the `employee-lastname` part from the URL, and then use that to go look up the corresponding data in an array.